# VBA 101 => Insert Rows after Last Row in Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I will preface this by saying that I am an extreme beginner with Visual Basic.  I took classes five or six years ago in college, and have since determined that I no longer know how to write code or did not pay enough attention in class.

Issue: I have a "table" that begins in D4.  I put table in quotation marks because it is more just a data set and I did not go through the process of actually inserted a table from the data ribbon.  I would like to take this table (the example has four incumbents) and copy this in the next available row in column D below this table, though I would prefer to include a blank row for aesthetics.  Please see below for a before and after of my "vision".  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Noticed I cannot paste images as a rookie, so if you need additional detail please reach out to me and I can provide you with the images.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
Sub SpecialCopy()
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("D4:D" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=Range("D" & lastRow + 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Couple of questions/comments.  It looks like I had to use the number 2 as opposed to 1 in the last qualifier to get the additional blank row.

When I rerun the macro a second time, it is showing four tables, though ideally it would only show 3 (one new table each button click).  Do you know how I would solve this or what is causing this issue?

Thank you so much for your help! Truly appreciate the quick response

Comment: The first time I use the macro it copies the rows in range D4:D18.  Now I have two tables (exactly what I want).  The second time I click the macro button, I end up with 4 tables (I would like 3).  Let me know if that doesn't make sense